# defaultdict with multiple parameters

Tags: python, string, dictionary, collections, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict initialized as:

```
w2i = defaultdict(lambda: len(w2i))
UNK = w2i["<unk>"]
```

So UNK will have value 0.
Now I add some more elements(words) to w2i with each key being mapped to the length of the dictionary at that instance.

Then if we perform:

```
w2i = defaultdict(lambda: UNK, w2i)
```

and try to access w2i with new or existing word keys, what will the result be? e.g. let's say "one" is a key existing in w2i and "two" is not in w2i. After redefining w2i as above what will the result of the following be?

```
onew2i = w2i["one"]
twow2i = w2i["two"]
```

Also, what do the 2 parameters in defaultdict represent. Most tutorials on defaultdict with lambda seem to have just 1 parameter.

Thanks!

Comment: Just run it and see for yourself? I'm failing to see what is the question here.

Comment: Note that ``lambda`` binds less than ``,``. ``defaultdict(lambda: UNK, w2i)`` is equivalent to ``defaultdict((lambda: UNK), w2i)`` – ``w2i`` is just the initial dict content, same as in ``dict(w2i)``. ["All remaining arguments are treated the same as if they were passed to the dict constructor, including keyword arguments."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using:

```
w2i = defaultdict(lambda: UNK, w2i)
```

to add words from a test dataset the words existing in w2i will be skipped, those not in w2i will be added with value 0(UNK).

So onew2i's value won't be changed, twow2i will have value 0.

Comment: "the words existing in w2i will be skipped" How so? Everything in the initial ``w2i`` is *copied into* the new dict – nothing is skipped. "So onew2i's value won't be changed, twow2i will have value 0." How so? Neither has an initial value to change, and both will have their value set to 0.

Comment: the words from the test data which might already be existing in w2i will not undergo any change in their values and directly copies as you mentioned. the words not in w2i already will be added with value 0. the question mentions "one" is a key already existing in w2i.